# How to remove Vuejs "scope is undefined' warning?

Tags: vue.js

As a beginner with Vue.js, I have a component that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="{{ data.uk_store_link }}">
      {{ data.title }} - {{ data.artist.name }}
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['data']
}
</script>
```

"data.artist.name" is present and correct in the object that is passed to the data prop. But how can I get rid of the warning that pops up about the nested artist name?

> [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "data.artist.name":
>   TypeError: scope.data.artist is undefined (found in component:
>   <release>)

ETA: Ah, sorry, yes, it would have been helpful to show the "data":

> { "id": 23182, "title": "Music from 'Likely Stories'",
>   "uk_store_link":
>   "http://store.roughtraderecords.com/...html",
>   "artist": { "id": 1176, "name": "Jarvis Cocker" } }

I've stripped out some fields there for brevity, but hopefully this demonstrates that data.artist.name does actually exist. It certainly gets successfully output to the page, despite the warning.

Comment: Please share complete `data` if possible ?

Comment: its probably because data.artist doesnt exist. when you use the component in the parent you need to bind your data property to a piece of data like <my-component :data="album"></my-component> and that album looks like { title: 'my world', artist: { name: 'justin bieber' } }

Comment: I've added the data as output in a {{ data | json }}. It's not that data.artist.name doesn't exist, I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ data.artist ? data.artist.name : '' }}
```

Comment: D'oh, you're right, it really is as simple as that. I was confused because every "data" did have a data.artist, but I guess there's a point in time before that's been established, where the warning gets given...